# Need to migrate production rundeck from 2.10.0 to 4.11.x. How?

Tags: rundeck

I've inherited a Rundeck v2.10.0 instance, and have been asked to upgrade/migrate to the latest v4.11.x version.   Looking at the upgrade documentation, upgrading seems to occur in small minor-revision increments.   As an alternative to performing dozens of incremental upgrades, is there anything else I can do (e.g, export v2.10.0 data and import into v4.11.x?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common scenario, the gap between Rundeck 2.10 and 4.11 is huge (really huge), so, the best approach here is to save your projects and [keys](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#export-import-keys) and then import it to a brand new instance. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#project-import-and-export). Make sure to try this in a non-prod environment first.

Comment: Thank You for the direction and link to documentation.  I did a quick review, and it looks straight forward.  This should save me massive amounts of time.  Thanks again.  Best, Peter

Comment: Any time Peter :-)